# Texture is rendered as a flat colored surface

Tags: rendering, texturing, windows

I'm using AMD ProRender and I can't get it to render a texture I applied to a cuboid properly. This is my node graph and material properties panel:
[image]

And this is what the render looks like:

[image]

Basically the floor should have a damaged concrete texture. I'm probably being an idiot and overlooking some setting. What am I doing wrong or how could I proceed to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you UV unwrap it, or did you tell the render to use some other texture coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When UV unwrapping, I hadn't selected all the sides of the object. Press A to select everything, then U to unwrap it all. Marking seams and unwrapping does nothing when there is nothing selected and there is no error message.

Comment: This is the answer. I just had to select all faces before unwrapping and now in can display the texture. Is it unclear?

Comment: It's better with your comment now, makes the procedure more consistent